# Make Apache handle jsonp requests so that we can cache them

Tags: apache, apache2, jsonp

In Apache I'm caching the http requests and I want also the cache jsonp requests. The problem is the fact the jsonp request comes with random cb params.

I want to use Apache mod (rewrite/substitute) to strip the incoming cb params from the URL but in the response add the call back wrapper. 
Similar to this VCL config for Varnish https://gist.github.com/simonw/640331

Comment: Something like this?  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/2.5.0/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/jsonp/AbstractJsonpOutInterceptor.java